# Getting 'Whitelabel Error Page' error in Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I am getting the following error when I am calling my dashboard home page.`http://localhost:8082/web/fix/dashboard`

[image]

What I understood from it is that the JSP file `/WEB-INF/jsp/dashboard.jsp` is missing somehow or maybe spring won't able to find it or maybe I did something wrong.

To make sure I tried decompiling the jar but JSP file was missing. don't know where it is?

I have placed JSP file in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/dashboard.jsp`.

**However, this problem only occurs while running an application using the jar file. It works fine in eclipse.**

`java -jar application.jar`

It is a maven project.

Application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
server.address=127.0.0.1
server.port=8082
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.fidel.fixadaptor</groupId>
<artifactId>fix-adaptor</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>fix-adaptor</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId> <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId> 
        <version>2.3.0</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId> <version>2.3.0</version> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quickfixj</groupId>
        <artifactId>quickfixj-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quickfixj</groupId>
        <artifactId>quickfixj-messages-fix50sp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
        <version>0.3m</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/web/")
public class WebController {

@Autowired
ConfigurationService configurationService;

@Autowired
private Destination destination;

@Autowired
private Gson gson;

@GetMapping(path = "fix/dashboard")
public String dashBoard(Model model) {

    // view to render
    return "dashboard";
}
}
```

Application Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.covacap.bloomberg")
public class CovacapTerminalRunner extends SpringBootServletInitializer 
implements CommandLineRunner {

/** The adaptor runner. */
@Autowired
CovacapRunner adaptorRunner;

/** The Constant LOGGER. */
private static final Logger LOGGER = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(CovacapTerminalRunner.class);

/**
 * The main method.
 *
 * @param args the arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
SpringApplication.run(CovacapTerminalRunner.class, args);
    try {
        String[] list = context.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        for (String string : list) {
            LOGGER.info(string);
        }
        context.getBean(AdaptorDestination.class).autoStart();

    } catch (BeansException | ConfigException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * 
 * @param args
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    // adaptorRunner.run(args);
}
}
```

Please help on this

Comment: can you share the stacktrace?

Comment: no error no exception at console, showing above error only in the browser

Comment: how are you packaging the jar?

Comment: `mvn clean package`

Answer (score 0):

Since the jsp files are missing and as you mentioned after decompiling the jar file the jsp files are not there means that maven doesn't copy them when you bundle the jar file.

Try telling maven to manually copy the webapp folder as a resource similar to the 
below snippet

```
<build>
    <resources>
      ...
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```